# Better way to identify a user in a url

Tags: security, social-networking, bookmarks, url-parameters, user-identification

I have written this other question [Is it secure to put the user id as a url parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551448/is-it-secure-to-put-the-user-id-as-a-url-parameter/38551467)

But I have doubts, I don't know in terms of security what is the best way to identify a user in a social network in a url so that it is bookmarkable.

For example:

- https://url?user= user name + unique number
- https://url?user= user id
- https://url?user= unique nickname
- ¿any other?

The last one would be a unique nick name different from the Name and Surnames.

Comment: Well Facebook is using the following: www.facebook.com/Name.Surname.Unique Number - so I would assume it's a pretty good way to do it.

Comment: I am thinking on using name.surname.uuid but uuid's are very large

Comment: How large are we talking?

Comment: like this 21EC2020-3AEA-4069-A2DD-08002B30309D

Comment: That's incredibly long for an ID. Maybe you should add some auto-incrementing ID for users that you only use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the user's unique name is constant (and not changeable) , then you can very well use that in the URL, security is not concern here unless you don't reveal sensitive informations.

But if you don't have any unique names , then you can use any hashed form of Ids in the URL , from which you can able to identify the user, like:

site.com/user/hash(id) , something like that to get short urls , if Id is random you can use that too